# Offline NT Password changer won't recognize the hard drive, which is a SCU device (not SATA), alternatives?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata, password-recovery

The device is show as following in devices in BIOS: SCU device 1 WDC WD 500...
Model is Lenovo ThinkStation S30.
What are the alternative software/method? There are several unlock software but I don't feel like paying for it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the answer is in the [FAQ](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/faq.html)

> It cannot find any Windows disks or paritions.
>
> If it cannot find any disks it is usally because the drivers for the
>   disk controller is not included in my image.
>   [...]
>   It is possible to use other boot CD / images (live linux
>   distributions), they contains a more complete graphical environment
>   that can be booted off CD / USB, and runs in memory without install

Or switch the HDD to one of the regular SATA ports if it isn't SAS.